# if condition for multiple methods in a class

Tags: python, class, methods

I'm writing in python to get a better feel for good practices when using classes. I've written a few methods for a couple classes; dog and person. I have introduced a new method for dog called die, defined below:

```
def die(self):
    if self.owner:
        self.owner.pets.discard(self)
    self.owner = None
    self.dead = True
```

Now I don't want to be able to use most of the other methods for a dead dog, ie a method on person to adopt a pet (person.adopt(self,pet)). Since there are many methods (and there may be more to come) with this condition, I would like to avoid adding an if statement to each method requiring the dog to be alive. Is there a way to simply not allow some methods given a condition such as self.dead == False?

Comment: Your example is a method to person, not to pet. So you'd want an if-statement in the person's `adopt` method to see if the pet is dead; not something in a pet's method.

Comment: Right but I have a lot of methods in person for which I would have to check if the pet is alive, is there a more elegant way of doing it?

Comment: What do you want the not-allowed methods to do: raise an AttributeError (that is, the method is simply gone from the class), raise a NotImplementedError, raise another error (e.g., ValueError), or do nothing (comparable to `pass`)?

Comment: Well I guess what I'm really asking is what is preferable way to handle this situation, it's not hard to imagine this sort of thing being used in a lot of other places so I was just trying to find out how other people handle it and if there's some preferred way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about using a decorator? You will have to decorate each function that requires the pet to be alive, but you will avoid having to write the if-logic over and over:

```
>>> def require_alive(func):
...     def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
...         if not self.alive:
...             raise Exception("Not alive")
...         return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
...     return wrapper
...
>>> def require_hungry(func):
...     def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
...         if not self.hungry:
...             print "Not hungry..."
...         else:
...             return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
...     return wrapper
...
>>> class Pet(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.alive = True
...         self.hungry = True
...     def die(self):
...         self.alive = False
...     @require_alive
...     @require_hungry
...     def eat(self):
...         print "Eating..."
...         self.hungry = False
...     @require_alive
...     def sleep(self):
...         print "Sleeping..."
...
>>> roofus = Pet()
>>> roofus.eat()
Eating...
>>> roofus.eat()
Not hungry...
>>> roofus.sleep()
Sleeping...
>>> roofus.die()
>>> roofus.eat()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in wrapper
Exception: Not alive
```

Comment: A similar decorator can be defined for `Person` methods, such as the `adopt`, which need to check the explicit argument rather than `self`.

Comment: Interesting, I've never encountered decorators before, but it seems like just what I was looking for. is the @require_alive decorator required before each method or just before all the methods that require a dog to be alive?

Comment: You define the decorator once (`def require_alive...`) and include the decorator (`@require_alive`) before *each* of the methods that require the dog to be alive. Decorators are difficult to understand when you first see them, but very powerful once understood.

Comment: Sorry maybe I worded my followup question poorly I meant to ask is do I need the decorator before each function that requires the dog to be alive or simply before a whole bunch of functions that require the dog to be alive?

Comment: I reworded my comment to make it more clear, and added an additional method to the Pet class to demonstrate.

Comment: Can I use multiple decorators by "stacking them" above a function?

Comment: Absolutely. I have updated my answer to include a second decorator on the `eat` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of methods to decorate, you may want to consider using a metaclass to do the work of applying it to all of them even though it longer than the answer you accepted. This has the advantage that the list of decorated methods would all be in one location — so it would be easier to change them and provides documentation. I've also made the decorator itself a staticmethod of the class since that's the only place it's used.

```
from functools import wraps

class MetaDeco(type):
    def __new__(metaclass, name, bases, attrs):
        cls = super(MetaDeco, metaclass).__new__(metaclass, name, bases, attrs)
        if 'meta_args' in attrs:
            decoratorname, methodnames = attrs['meta_args']
            decorator = getattr(cls, decoratorname)
            for methodname in methodnames:
                setattr(cls, methodname, decorator(getattr(cls, methodname)))
            del attrs['meta_args']  # clean up
        return cls

class Pet(object):
    __metaclass__ = MetaDeco  # in Python 3 use Pet(metalcass=MetaDeco)
    meta_args = ('require_alive', ('eat', 'sleep'))

    @staticmethod
    def require_alive(method):
        @wraps(method)
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if self.dead:
                raise Exception("Not alive")
            return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper

    def __init__(self, owner):
        self.owner = owner
        self.dead = False

    def die(self):
        self.owner = None
        self.dead = True

    def eat(self):
        print("Eating...")

    def sleep(self):
        print("Sleeping...")

p = Pet('Alex')
p.eat()  # -> Eating...
p.sleep()  # -> Sleeping...
p.die()
p.eat()  # will raise exception
```